# GeoCharts, how to only display the countries name and not the value?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Similar to this post about showing countries names: [GeoCharts how to show country names instead of codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651847/geocharts-how-to-show-country-names-instead-of-codes)

But with the added caveat of excluding the numerical value that also displays. The issue is I just want certain countries to display depending on the value but the value in itself is a meaningless token.

Comment: you can use a custom tooltip, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64645606/5090771)...

Comment: For some reason, when I use this, the functions I have that take in 'value' don't work anymore